# apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full gives dependency error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-fuerte-desktop-full : Depends: ros-fuerte-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.7-s1367606056~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo (= 1.6.16-s1367570782~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization (= 1.8.17-s1367591457~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-perception-pcl (= 1.2.3-s1367556503~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-image-pipeline (= 1.8.5-s1367570800~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model (= 1.8.1-s1367542439~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization-tutorials (= 0.6.3-s1367606405~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-laser-pipeline (= 1.4.5-s1367570620~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-navigation (= 1.8.3-s1367591379~precise) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm using following Linux.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64218/apt-get-install-ros-fuerte-desktop-full-gives-dependency-error./) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on 2013-06-03**:
I did $ sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update, but same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do following to regenerate (reinstall) all apt packages.

```
dpkg --get-selections | awk '$2=="install" {
    system ("sudo apt-get install -y --reinstall " $1)
}'
```

---

Originally posted by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) with karma: 314 on 2013-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1